# How to plot a variable dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe with a variable number of stock prices. In other words, I have to be able to plot the entire Dataframe, because I may encounter 1 to 10 stocks prices.
The x axis are dates, the Y axis are Stock prices. Here is a sample of my Df:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(all_Assets)
 df2 = df.transpose()
 print(df2)
```

```
                                Close       Close       Close
Date                                                         
2018-12-12 00:00:00-05:00   40.802803   24.440001  104.500526
2018-12-13 00:00:00-05:00   41.249191   25.119333  104.854965
2018-12-14 00:00:00-05:00   39.929325   24.380667  101.578560
2018-12-17 00:00:00-05:00   39.557732   23.228001   98.570381
2018-12-18 00:00:00-05:00   40.071678   22.468666   99.605057
```

This is not working

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(df2, mode='lines'),)
```

I need to plot this entire dataframe on a single chart, with 3 different lines. But the code has to adapt automatically if there is a fourth stock, fifth stock e.g. By the way , I want it to be a **Logarithmic plot**.

Comment: Are you column names really duplicated?

Comment: no i have to change them upper in my code

Comment: but they can't be parameters because they may vary

Comment: Can you make a good reproducible example _showing different column names_ with enough data the make the plot, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plots-on-date-axes), so let's try to graph it in wide and long format with express and in wide and long format with the graph object. You can choose from these four types to do what you need.

- express wide format

```
df.head()
date    GOOG    AAPL    AMZN    FB  NFLX    MSFT
0   2018-01-01  1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
1   2018-01-08  1.018172    1.011943    1.061881    0.959968    1.053526    1.015988
2   2018-01-15  1.032008    1.019771    1.053240    0.970243    1.049860    1.020524
3   2018-01-22  1.066783    0.980057    1.140676    1.016858    1.307681    1.066561
4   2018-01-29  1.008773    0.917143    1.163374    1.018357    1.273537    1.040708

import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=df.columns[1:])
fig.show()
```

[image]

- express long format

```
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='date', value_vars=df.columns[1:],var_name='ticker')
px.line(df_long, x='date', y='value', color='ticker')
```

- graph_objects wide format

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for ticker in df.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df[ticker], name=ticker))

fig.show()
```

- graph_objects long format

```
fig = go.Figure()

for ticker in df_long.ticker.unique():
    dff = df_long.query('ticker == @ticker')
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['date'], y=dff['value'], name=ticker))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). A minimal working example for your case should be just

```
df2.plot()
```

. Then just play around with the plot() method and your df2 dataframe to get exactly the output you need.